# paging through NetFlix odata results

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata, netflix

I am playing around with the Netflix odata service to get a better understanding of how to consume odata data.

In VS 2010 I added a service reference to the NetFlix odata service. I then wrote this code which returns only some of the data.

```
        var cat = new NetflixCatalog(new Uri("http://odata.netflix.com/v1/Catalog/"));

        var x = from t in cat.Titles
                where t.ReleaseYear == 2009
                select t;

        foreach (Title title in x)
        {
            ProcessTitle(title);
        }
```

I looked at the uri generated for the call and ran it in a browser. The atom feed it returns has this element at the end

```
  <link rel="next" href="http://odata.netflix.com:20000/v1/Catalog/Titles()/?$filter=ReleaseYear%20eq%202009&amp;$orderby=AverageRating%20desc&amp;$skiptoken=3.9D,'BVqRa'" />
```

This is the a link that will retrieve the next set of data (paging done by Netflix). My question is how do I get my code to access this next batch of data and the next etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The query can be cast to DataServiceQuery, which has a method called Execute which returns the results as QueryOperationResponse which has a GetContinuation method, which returns a continuation object representing the next link.
A rough code to go through all the titles could look like this:

```
var cat = new NetflixCatalog(new Uri("http://odata.netflix.com/v1/Catalog/"));

var x = from t in cat.Titles
        where t.ReleaseYear == 2009
        select t;
var response = (QueryOperationResponse<Title>)((DataServiceQuery<Title>)x).Execute();

while (true)
{
    foreach (Title title in response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(title.Name);
    }

    var continuation = response.GetContinuation();
    if (continuation == null)
    {
        break;
    }

    response = cat.Execute(continuation);
}
```

Comment: Vitek, I am trying to implement this in a WPF showing next and previous button. Could you please advice me on the same?

Comment: The server driven paging is forward only. So it really can only get the next page. You would have to remember the previous page yourself. Maybe it would be better if you would use client driven paging. So for example ~/Titles?$top=10&$skip=20 (this gets the third page of size 10). If your top value is smaller than the page size limit on the server you won't see the continuations at all. And you can easily compute the URL to hit for your previous and next buttons.