# While fetching records from wcf odata service entities, It returns only top 20 records from the entity. How can i increase the limit 20 to 100?

Tags: wcf, odata, wcf-data-services, devextreme

Hi I'm working on devextreme multi channel app and i have a view which shows list of cities fetching from sql server via wcf odata service entity. I'm facing a problem that it fetches only top 20 records and it skips the remaining records. I googled and found that there's a property in wcf called

> MaxResultSetsPerCollection

to increase the return result of a entity. I have declared it as `config.MaxResultSetsPerCollection =100`

But it doesn't work. Still It fetches only top 20 records. Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to increase return records size odata service from client side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010497/how-to-increase-return-records-size-odata-service-from-client-side)

Comment: Check your dataSource configuration. I suppose, you use the default [pageSize](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/Configuration/?version=15_2#pageSize) option.

Comment: Thank you Sergey. This solved my Issue.. thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome! I've put this information to the answer. So, you can mark it as correct and close this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you use the default [pageSize](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/Configuration/?version=15_2#pageSize) option. You can change it like below:

```
var ds = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
   // the data source configuration

   pageSize: 100 // required page size
});
```