# Returns all rows from a Odata wcf service

Tags: linq, odata

I am trying to return all the rows in my linq query and iterate through it to do other business logic. My code sample goes like this : -

```
var ctx = new ServiceRelated.EmsODataContext(serviceExecutionUri);
var andondata = from data in ctx.SEWInstanceViewItems
                select new { ID = data.SEWInstanceID, ServiceType =          data.ServiceTypeName, Complex = data.EventArea, AssignedTo = data.AssignedTo, Claimed = data.Status };

foreach (var boarddata in andondata)
{
    string strComeplex = boarddata.Complex.ToString();
}
```

I realised in the code as well as in the linqpad that query is only returning a 50 rows inspite of returning all rows (which is more than 80) and providing a link to go to next page.

I assume that there is some server side page size has been defined. Please guide me with a sample code to access all the rows at one go.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer has some sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120467/paging-through-netflix-odata-results/4124970#4124970

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the resultset page size to a large enough size using [SetEntitySetPageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration.setentitysetpagesize%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)